# Squirrel SQL display icon disappears when Squirrel is running

Tags: java, macos, icons, squirrel-sql

I am running Squirrel (snapshot ID from about screen 20140813_1954) on Mac OS X Mavericks.  I have it installed permanently in the menu bar. The acorn Icon shows up there when Squirrel is not running.  When I launch Squirrel it starts up fine, but the acorn icon disappears and is replaced by the default java process icon (the stylized blue coffee cup with red steam). When I exit squirrel, the acorn icon returns.

I know this is not a big problem, but I am curious why that is happening, and if there is anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem. I was able to resolve it using the answer found in this bug report:

http://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1099/

```
To fix it, add -Xdock:icon=../acorn.icns -Xdock:name=Squirrel to MACOSX_SQUIRREL_PROPS in squirrel-sql.sh.
```

I found the squirrel-sql.sh file here:

```
/Applications/SQuirreLSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/squirrel-sql.sh
```